# Edit button not appear

Tags: visualforce

I have created VF page based on read only mode and edit mode. In my VF page edit button not appeared.

My VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OutputAndInputMode_Class"  >
    <apex:detail inlineEdit="true"/> 
    <apex:form id="pb"  >
        <apex:pageBlock mode="inlineEdit" >

            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!saveRender}" >
                <apex:inputField value="{!newAccount.Name}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Fax}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!editRender}" >
                <apex:outputField value="{!newAccount.Name}" >
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"/>                </apex:outputField>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Account.Fax}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton id="editButton" value="Edit" action="{!edit}"/>
                <apex:commandButton id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>     

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class OutputAndInputMode_Class {

    public boolean saveRender{get;set;}
    public boolean editRender{get;set;}   
    public Account newAccount{get;set;} 
    public String Name{get;set;}

    public OutputAndInputMode_Class(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        newAccount = new Account();
        saveRender = true;
        editRender = false;
    }
    public PageReference Save(){
        insert newAccount;
        saveRender = false;
        editRender = true;
        return null;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have edit access for Account object?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not seeing Edit button is because you are not passing the id into the url of your Visualforce page. To make it clear, I am pretty sure you are using an url like this:

https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/AccountEditPage

Instead, you should be using:

https://c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/AccountEditPage?id=[AccountId]

Just pass the account Id and it will be shown.

Comment: I'm not able to pass my id to url..

Comment: @JanaShree you definitely can. I copied exactly your code into my org and I can do it.